# Universal Image Loader and OutOfMemory

Tags: android

When I use universal-image-loader to load many images,the error of OutOfMemory always occur.How can I set ImageLoaderConfiguration and DisplayImageOptions to avoid this error？

Comment: share configuration and options

Comment: .threadPoolSize(3)
.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) 
.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
.diskCacheFileCount(100)
.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
.memoryCacheSize(2*1024*1024)
.diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cacheDir))
.diskCacheSize(50*1024*1024)
.memoryCacheExtraOptions(200, 200)

Comment: options：.cacheInMemory(false)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) 
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .delayBeforeLoading(100)
       .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
       .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
       .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(200))
       .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.picture)
       .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.picture)

Comment: remove .memoryCacheSize(2*1024*1024)  and check

Comment: Thanks for your help , I will have a try.

Comment: It can not works well.